# EntityFramework Package Installation Defaults to SQL Server 2014 LocalDb Connection

Tags: entity-framework

After spending a fair amount of time figuring out why a simple EF project could not connect to the database to create the database. I learned that the LocalDbConnectionFactory settings in .config file are set to use a SQL 2014 connection string and I don't have SQL 2014 installed

I thought maybe it's built into EF 6.1 so I removed it and added the EF 5.0.0 package and it also sets .config file up for a SQL 2014 localDb connection

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v12.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
```

How does the NuGet package installation decide to put the '12.0' as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in EF 6.1, it has been documented on [codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2246)